# Why doesn't there exist the following Boolean identities?

Tags: boolean-algebra

There are various Boolean identities some of which are as follows:

- $A + A = A$
- $A . A = A$
- $A + 1 = 1$
- $AB = BA$
- $A + AB = A$

and the list goes on

But why doesn't there exist the following Boolean identities which to me seems correct ?

1) $A + B = 1$

2) $A \cdot B = 0$

[Proof of above identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLFd5.png)

thanks for your precious time.

Comment: can you explain a bit more the question

Comment: I edited the question check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if $A=B=0$ then $A+B=0$ which makes the first invalid. And if $A=B=1$ it makes $A\cdot B=1$ which makes the second invalid.

Your "proof" is flawed since the truth table doesn't include **all** combination of values for $A$ and $B$. A proper truth table is:

$$\begin{matrix}
A & B & A+B & A\cdot B \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0   & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 1   & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: But A and B are two different variable how can they have same value 
 if you assign 1 to A then you can't assign same to B ??????????

Comment: Just because they are different doesn't require them to be different. How do you interpret distributive laws ($A(B+C)= AB+AC$)? If you require $A$, $B$ and $C$ to have different values you'd run into serious problems.

Comment: thanks got you. I thought maybe this would be interesting question.